# NavigationItem.rightBarButtonItem is not working

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, rightbarbuttonitem

Here is Share Button Initialized:

```
let shareButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ShareButtonCircle"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(shareButtonTapped))
```

Here is Objc method:

```
print("Share Button Clicked")
    let topicTitleAndDesc = [self]
    let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: topicTitleAndDesc, applicationActivities: nil)
    present(vc, animated: true)
```

viewDidLoad:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = shareButton
```

Showing on screen but not performing action:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Was it working in swift 4.2?

Comment: So your title shouldn't have said it's not working in swift 5 specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't face any problem with below code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let shareButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ShareButtonCircle"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(shareButtonTapped))
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = shareButton
}

@objc func shareButtonTapped() {
        print("Share Button Clicked")
        let topicTitleAndDesc = [self]
        let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: topicTitleAndDesc, applicationActivities: nil)
        present(vc, animated: true)
    }
```

[RESULT HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpeHF.png)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to share a UIViewController which is why you not getting any response. Try changing the items as follows:

```
let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [String(describing: self)], applicationActivities: nil)
```

Comment: i have tried, just using print statement, button is not called objc method

Comment: @UmerKhan If the print statement is not getting executed something else is wrong. Which cannot be found from your piece of code, need more context.